# how do I get a unique time out from the access database in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
OleDbConnection myAccessConn = myAccessConnection();
        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        string orderId = null, Checkintime=null, RoomPrice=null, ReceiptNo=null;
        decimal totalfoodamount = 0;

        try
        {
            myAccessConn.Open();

            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            DateTime dateOnly = startTime.Date;
            DateTime endDateOnly = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToLocalTime().Date;

            string sqlStatement = "select ID,Checkintime, RoomPrice, OrderNo from Orders where RoomType='" + selectedRoom.Key + "' and RoomNumber =" + selectedRoom.Value + " and Checkintime between '" + dateOnly +"' and '"+endDateOnly+"'";
            myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, myAccessConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Orders");

            DataTableCollection dta = myDataSet.Tables;
            DataColumnCollection drc = myDataSet.Tables["Orders"].Columns;
            DataRowCollection dra = myDataSet.Tables["Orders"].Rows;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dra)
            {
                orderId= dr[0].ToString();
                Checkintime= dr[1].ToString();
                RoomPrice= dr[2].ToString();
                ReceiptNo= dr[3].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("orderid: "+orderId+", Checkintime:  "+Checkintime+", RoomPrice: "+RoomPrice+", ReceiptNo: "+ReceiptNo+"");

            }
```

I tried doing this method but it shows an exception :{"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."} so that it would not pick out 2 same timings on different days.

Comment: why not catch a TimeoutException (or whatever the exception is for Access Timeouts or DB Timeouts) in the catch block ?

Comment: For me this isnt a clear question, but I feel it should be.  "SelectedRoom" clearly has a key and value, you have todays date, and tomorrows date. But comparing it to a date/time field. You probably just need to make that todays date with "00:00:00" and tomorrows date with "00:00:00"  so you're comparing a datetime with datetime.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to do neither from the question nor from the codes. The code however have potential error that you are not using parameters but instead crafting an SQL string using + ... + which is a no-no. I revised part of your code but couldn't go further as I couldn't understand what you are doing:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().Date;
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToLocalTime().Date;

string sqlStatement = @"select ID,Checkintime, RoomPrice, OrderNo 
   from Orders 
   where RoomType=@roomType and 
   RoomNumber = @roomNumber and 
   Checkintime >= @start and CheckinTime < @end";

myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, myAccessConn);
myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomType", selectedRoom.Key);
myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomNumber", selectedRoom.Value);
myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", startTime);
myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", endTime);

OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand,myAccessConn);
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Orders");
```